# Confusion when defining a sheaf on a basis of open sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

This question relates to Perrin's [Algebraic Geometry: An Introduction](http://www.math.unam.mx/javier/Perrin.pdf), specifically Chapter III, Lemma 2.1. In his definition of $\bar{\mathcal{F}}$, if $U_i$ is a basic open set which isn't contained in $U$, how can we say that $s|_{U_i} \in \mathcal{F}(U_i)$? Specifically, how are we expected to define $s|_{U_i}$ at points of $U_i \backslash U$?

Comment: I guess that when he writes that $U$ is covered by the $U_i$, then he means that $U$ is the union of the $U_i$. In particular I think he assumes that the $U_i$ are contained in $U$.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd been thinking as well. Thanks.